# nativescript sample projects fail with error Command ant failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, ant, nativescript

I went through the setup steps - on mac - but the sample nativescript projects all fail with the same error.

"Command ant failed with exit code 1"

Here is the log trace:
https://gist.github.com/getsetbro/c0225e8fc493d57b3f64

Other info
Android Studio on this mac run projects fine in emulators and connected devices
The same projects run in ios emulator without errors.

I installed JDK 8, never had version 7 on this system.

Answer (score 1):

I see the following error in the logs.

Cannot run program "/Users/sb/Documents/Dev/nativescript/test_nativescript/platforms/android/${aapt}"

I might be wrong but it seems **aapt** tool is missing from your $PATH environment variable. If this is the case, try adding **<ANDROID_SDK_ROOT>/tools** to  $PATH